# Rails change default URL's

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, url, routes

Im using rails for an app and I scaffolded the User database. I have a show.html.erb page for each user, but currently the URL's are /users/1 or /users/2, I want the URL's to be a random number, or the timestamp of creatation. So something like /users/201109123121 or even just a random;y generated number.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, define `to_param` in your `User` model:

```
def to_param
  timestamp
end
```

And define the `timestamp` attribute on your model and set it in a `before_create`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_timestamp

  # model code goes here
  def set_timestamp
    self.timestamp = created_at.to_i
  end
```

But if two users were created at precisely the same second, you will run into trouble. You may want to make this slightly more random than that. You will also now need to find them based on that field:

```
  User.find_by_timestamp(params[:id])
```

Comment: +1 on this not being a great idea; consider using a GUID instead if it's really important.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your Gemfile

```
gem 'uuidtools'
```

Then do

```
#models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_create :set_uuid

    # model code goes here
    def set_uuid
        self.uuid = UUIDTools::UUID.timestamp_create.to_s
    end
end
```

Then you request it like so.

```
User.find_by_uuid(params[:id])
```

Unlike the above answer this should significantly reduce the likelihood of a race condition as that's the point of uuid (universal unique identifier)